# racketunit check is not throwing exception

Tags: testing, racket

`(check < 4 3)` is returning an error message on the screen but the function also returns `#<void>`. I was expecting it to return only an exception and not void. Do I understand the following [racket doc](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=check#%28part._.Checks%29) incorrectly:

"If the condition holds the check evaluates to (void). If the condition doesn’t hold the check raises an instance of exn:test:check with information detailing the failure."

```
> (display (check < 4 3))
--------------------
FAILURE
name:       check
location:   (|interactions from an unsaved editor| 75 11 1868 13)
expression: (check < 4 3)
params:     (#<procedure:<> 4 3)

. . Check failure
--------------------
#<void>
>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your interpretation makes sense and that the docs are written in a misleading way, though maybe not technically incorrect.

Looking at the implementation, I think checks are meant to always return `#<void>` (see [this line](https://github.com/racket/rackunit/blob/master/rackunit-lib/rackunit/private/check.rkt#L135)).

When a check fails, however, there actually is an exception raised. It's just that by default it is always caught and converted into an error printout instead. That means the exception is not normally caught outside of the `check` so it effectively always returns `#<void>`.

You can adjust this behavior by parameterizing the [`current-check-around`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/internals.html?q=check#%28def._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._current-check-around%29%29) parameter. Here's an example:

```
-> (require rackunit)
-> (define (my-check-around thunk)
     (with-handlers ([exn:test:check? (λ (e) (raise e))])
       (thunk)))
-> (parameterize ([current-check-around my-check-around])
     (check < 4 3))
; Check failure [,bt for context]
```

The `raise` call in the handler propagates the exception further and it's caught by the REPL. If you just want to customize how the exception is handled, you can also parameterize [`current-check-handler`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/internals.html?q=check#%28def._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._current-check-handler%29%29) instead.

---

I pushed a fix to the rackunit docs, so in a future Racket version the docs should be clearer about this issue.

Comment: Thanks Asumu. Your help much appreciated.